# Origin of a tune to Baruch Kel Elyon

Tags: shabbat, song-poetry, provenance

When I was growing up in the 1980s, I heard a tune to ["ברוך קל עליון"](//he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F) that [I've now reproduced to the best of my recollection](//drive.google.com/file/d/1KLcRZfoXZw4amNA0SIpAnGZjYcbecG5Q), except that I sang it a bit faster than I recall it having been sung. Does anyone know its provenance?

(The tune is not on [the `piyut.org.il` list](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nlis/he/song/pages/results.aspx#query=any,contains,%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F). For those who can't or won't hear the audio file linked to above, I'll try to describe the tune, though as I've no musical training the description may seem odd to those with it and I'd appreciate edits from those who've heard the audio file. The first stanza is a march. The second is, too, I suppose, but with a different tune. The third stanza has the same tune as the first; no other two stanzas share a tune. The fourth and fifth stanzas are in waltz time; the fourth and sixth are the least lively of the seven stanzas. The sixth stanza starts off almost tuneless though it certainly has a tune by its end; I don't know what time it's in. The seventh (last) stanza is I think no longer in waltz time.)

Comment: Based on the melody, it should be something late 19th century/early 20th century German or American composition.